# How to test external services from inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, integration-testing

We recently switched our system over to Docker.  This involves a number of containers- one for the app, one for mysql, etc.  However, I have now hit a problem I didn't think about before starting :)

We have a number of system level integration tests that are designed to test interaction with external services.  Doing things like stopping redis, issuing a request, checking that the system responds correctly, and then restarting redis and making sure it reconnects correctly.  Before, this was pretty simple-

```
subprocess.call('service redis stop')
```

for example.  But now... the app container with our python code doesn't have any control over the external server where redis lives.  Does anyone have any ideas for the best way to adapt the existing tests to work properly in the new environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run the tests on the host and use `docker` commands to start and stop the containers containing the services you want to enable/disable.

If you want to get fancy, you could create a container that mounts the docker unix socket inside so that you can talk to docker on the host. That is essentially giving root access on the host to that container though, so be careful if you do go this route.

Comment: This wound up being the correct solution.  In a copy of our application container, we mounted the docker socket and binary, and then rewrote the 'service stop redis' type commands to be more like 'docker stop redis'.  Thanks!